# What is causing this too few arguments error?

Tags: c++

I am working on getting inputs from keyboard and pass them to variales in C++. I am getting too few argument error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void_fullname(char fname, char lname) {
    printf("Enter Your First Name\n");
    scanf( "%d", &fname );
    printf("Enter Your Last Name\n");
    scanf( "%d", &lname );
    printf("Welcome: %d\n",First Name + Last Name)\n");
}

int main() {
    printf( "1.Full Name\n" );
    printf( "2.Exit\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &input );
    switch ( input ) {
        case 1:          
            void_fullname();
            break;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I have removed the C# tag and added C++. This is not C#. Also, you're calling `void_fullname()` which expects two **single** `char`'s.. not a string of them. As it stands, your code is horribly broken and I would suggest reading up on basic type and function usage.

Comment: How are you not getting multiple compiler errors earlier in your code?

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to figure what you're puzzled by. You write a function with two parameters, `void_fullname(char fname, char lname)`, you then call it with zero parameters, `void_fullname();`, the compiler then tells you exactly what you've done wrong. Maybe reading an introductory book on C++ will help?

I'm afraid to say there are many other errors in your code, as you'll discover once you've got the compiler errors out the way.

Here's a few tips,

1) `char` means a single char, not a sequence of chars. For something like a name you need a char array or a string.

2) `%d` is not the correct format specifier to read in character data.

3) When you wish to return data in the parameter of a function, you should pass a pointer or a reference to that function.

And so on... I think you should start with something simpler. For instance you will probably find this easier without writing any functions apart from main. Add some functions later when you've got it working without functions first. Start slowly and build up in small steps.

Comment: i guss I should have been cleared on the sample script I posted above, I was just trying to illustrate what I wanted to accomplish. I will go back and research more

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving `void_fullname()` any arguments

```
switch ( input ) {
    case 1:          
    void_fullname(); // Need args here
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is expecting two arguments, `fname` and `lname`

```
case 1:          
    void_fullname();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling void_fullname without any parameters, it requires 2 parameters.